# Cannot found ResourceDictionary in specific folder

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've this application structure:

```
AppName
    Resources
        Languages
            en.xaml
            it.xaml
```

I'm trying to load a specific `ResourceDictionary` based on the `CurrentCulture` of the software that I set when the application start, a little example:

```
var dict = new ResourceDictionary();
string currentLang = "it-IT";

if (currentLang == "it-IT")
{
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("it");
    Application.LoadComponent(dict, new Uri("..\\Resources\\Languages\\it.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
else
{
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en");
    Application.LoadComponent(dict, new Uri("..\\Resources\\Languages\\en.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

when the code reach this line: `Application.LoadComponent(dict, new Uri("..\\Resources\\Languages\\it.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`

I get this error:

> System.Exception: 'A resource identified by the URI' ..\Resources\Languages\it.xaml 'is not available for the' System.Windows.ResourceDictionary 'component.'

why happen this?

Thanks for any explaination.

Comment: What is GetCurrentLangDict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this. I am doing like this and it finds them.

```
Application.LoadComponent(dict, new Uri("pack:\\application:,,,\YourDLL;\\component\\Resources\\Languages\\en.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
string currentLang = "it-IT";

if (currentLang == "it-IT")
{
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("it");
    MainWindow.AppWindow.lsVm.GetCurrentLangDict=(ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("..\\Resources\\Languages\\it.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
else
{
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en");
    MainWindow.AppWindow.lsVm.GetCurrentLangDict=(ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("..\\Resources\\Languages\\en.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should load the resource dictionary and merge into your `App.xaml`:

```
ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("/Resources/Languages/it.xaml", UriKind.Relative) };
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
```